# Непонятен обратный порядок выполнения кода

Tags: javascript

Отображается строка 'Доброе утро',
хотя **hourNow** *в консоли равен 14*

```js
    let today = new Date();
    let hourNow = today.getHours();
    let greeting;
    
    if (hourNow > 8) {
        greeting = 'Доброе утро';
    } else if (hourNow > 13) {
     greeting = 'Добрый день';     
    } else if (hourNow > 18) {
        greeting = 'Добрый вечер';
    } else if (hourNow > 23) {
        greeting = 'Доброй ночи';
    } else {
        greeting = '404';
    }
    
    document.write('<h2>' + greeting + '</h2>');
```

Но все верно, если поменять порядок на такой:

```js
let today = new Date();
let hourNow = today.getHours();
let greeting;

  if (hourNow > 23) {
        greeting = 'Доброй ночи';
    } else if (hourNow > 18) {
     greeting = 'Добрый вечер';     
    } else if (hourNow > 13) {
        greeting = 'Добрый день';
    } else if (hourNow > 8) {
        greeting = 'Доброе утро';
    } else {
        greeting = '404';
    }

document.write('<h2>' + greeting + '</h2>');
```

подскажите почему так?

Comment: Потому что 14 > 8.

Comment: Благодарю за обратную связь и за ваши развернутые ответы!

Answer (score 1):

Превратимся в компьютер. Попадаем на строчку

```
if (hourNow > 8) {
```

`hourNow` равно 14. 14 больше 8. Отлично, выполняем

```
greeting = 'Доброе утро';
```

и на этом завершаем выполнение блока `if..else if..else`.

Во втором варианте условия `if (hourNow > 23)` и `else if (hourNow > 18)` не верны, и выполнение доходит до `else if (hourNow > 13)`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const today = new Date();
const hour_now = today.getHours();

function getGreeting(hours) {
    const greetings = [
        [0, 'Доброй ночи'],
        [8, 'Доброе утро'],
        [13, 'Добрый день'],
        [18, 'Добрый вечер'],
        [23, 'Доброй ночи'],
    ].reverse();
    const greeting = greetings.find(([hour]) => hour <= hours);
    return greeting ? greeting[1] : '404';
}

console.log(7, getGreeting(7));
console.log(8, getGreeting(8));
console.log(14, getGreeting(14));
console.log(18, getGreeting(18));
console.log(23, getGreeting(23));

document.write('<h2>' + getGreeting(hour_now) + '</h2>');
```